# Vue typescript recursive component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, recursion

I have a simple typescript component with recursion:

```js
<template>
  <div :style="{ paddingLeft: depth * 20 + 'px' }">
    <h1>Level {{ depth }}</h1>
    <div v-if="depth < 2">
      <Recursive v-for="i in 3" :key="i" :depth="depth + 1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import * as Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  components: { Recursive }
})
class Recursive extends Vue {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  depth!: number;
}

export default Recursive;
</script>
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-typescript-recursive-12u3q?file=/src/components/Recursive.vue

It works fine in development mode.

But once I make a build - recursive imports will be compiled into these kind of strings:

`<!--function(e,n,r,o){return ln(t,e,n,r,o,!0)}-->` instead of html.

What should I do to make the recursion work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to set the name of the component in `@Component` decorator:

```js
@Component({
  name: 'Recursive',
  components: { Recursive }
})
```

This code will be working both in development and compiled modes.

Comment: I love you! Strange thing, as you don't get any hint what is wrong. And I still don't get why it is working in dev mode...

Comment: Glad it helped ❤️  Have no idea why is it still working in dev mode ‍♂️

Comment: Setting the `name` solved it for me as well. However, for me defining the `components: { Recursive }` section causes an error, so I just removed it. Some useful links I came across:  https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6385#issuecomment-748076310 and https://medium.com/js-dojo/build-a-collapsible-tree-menu-with-vue-js-recursive-components-e598306dc3d1 (I know the second link is for non-typescript, but it might still be useful for context)